# In Rummikub, Is it possible to change the location of a joker inside a meld?

Tags: rummikub, joker

In Rummikub, assume there is a Run of Joker, R4, R5 on the board.  Is it possible to move the joker to the other end of the run and to add a R7? So the new Run is R4, R5, Joker, R7.

Comment: Please do not use codeblocks for anything that is not actual code. This seems to be something you'd be aware of, but now certainly should be. @Cohensius

Comment: @Nij, I did not know that preformatted text is reserved only for actual code.  I mean, on Stack overflow i would not use it anything but code but here at Board & Card Games that could improve readability (in my opinion).

Comment: It actively interferes with accessibility. We already have emphasis and strong emphasis, and table formatting. Please don't make life harder for people.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the version of the rules are being played.

The [older Pressman Toys rules](https://www.pressmantoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/0400G10_V15_0816_Rummikub_RULES.pdf) require matching both the color and number of the tile represented by the joker.

> On future turns, a joker can be retrieved from a set on the
> table by a player who can replace it during his/her turn with a tile of the same number and color the joker
> represents.

Where the [newer rules from 2019](https://rummikub.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2600-English-1.pdf) for the joker state

> a joker can be retrieved from a set on the table
> by a player who can replace it during his/her turn with any tiles that can keep the set legitimate.

So as long as the set remains legitimate after you have manipulated the tiles you can reclaim the joker.

This is further reinforced by example (3.) from the rules, where a B8 Joker is reclaimed by a B5 tile
[image: A joker representing B8 being reclaimed in exchange for a B5 tile]

Comment: I remember that this rule has been changed several times though the reeditions of Rummikub, so if the OP is playing with an older box and checks their ruleset, they might find the exact opposite of your answer.

Comment: interesting, it looks like there are 3 main rules variants, but only two options for joker replacement rules.